# usernam.get() and password.get() in def login() ...dont work

Tags: python

I don't know why it dont work even when I copy somone code it work but when I do my code it dont work .

I want to get the username and the password so I can verify the login else it will show a message box.

```
from tkinter import *
    
def login():

    usrnam = username.get()
    paswrd = password.get()

    print(username)


root = Tk()
photo = PhotoImage(file='small logo.png')
root.geometry('300x500+450+100')
root.title('Clinique nouadhibou')
root.config(background='white')
root.iconphoto(True,photo)


label1 = Label(root, text="bonjour !", font=('Arial', 20, 'bold'), bg='white', fg='green', relief=RAISED, bd=10, image=photo, compound='top').pack()

username = Entry(root).place(x=95, y=320)

password = Entry(root, show='*').place(x=95, y=340)


who_is_this = Checkbutton(root).place(x=0, y=480)
button = Button(root, text='Enter !', command=login).place(x=137, y=360)
button = Button(root, text='SORTIR!', command=quit).place(x=130, y=470)

root.mainloop()
```

It give me this error:

```
File "clinique.py", line 14, in login
   usrnam = username.get()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.place()` returns `None`. You should declare the widget on one line, and place it on the next one, then reference the declaration.

Example:

```
# old code
username = Entry(root).place(x=95, y=320)

password = Entry(root, show='*').place(x=95, y=340)

# new code
username = Entry(root)
username.place(x=95, y=320)

password = Entry(root, show='*')
password.place(x=95, y=340)
```